# Can I make a game use FXAA using NVidia application profiles?

Tags: nvidia, games, steam, antialiasing

I would like to be able to run Team Fortress 2 with FXAA enabled, but the only way I know how is to turn on in NVidia settings "enhance application settings" which effects all games and apps using OpenGL. I see that in the latest beta driver they've added "application profile" support, which looks to allow you to have special settings for single apps. Is their any way I could use this to enable FXAA just for Team Fortress 2?